# Add two fields in auto suggestion in solr

Tags: search, solr, autocomplete, lucene

I have two field in Solr from which I want to generate auto suggest,

and also I want to show result distinguishly for name and college. For eg. if I search for "nan" the auto suggest sholud give result with both fields like for name it is nandy and college nandas institute. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) you can copy name and college field to the copyField and use this field as a suggester.

Comment: Does not fulfill the requirement of distinquishing between the suggestions' fields of origin, though.